# Get difference of lists flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `[3,5,6,7,9,10]`. I want to get the difference of the first list and the second list.

The expected output would be `[1,2,4]` since those are the only elements in only list 1 and not list 2.

I'm using Flutter and Dart. I looked this up on the internet, I know it seems like a simple question but I couldn't find anything.

Should be irrelevant but I'm using publishing for iOS

I'd prefer an answer without just a foreach loop, im looking to see if there is a library for it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```dart
List<double> first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
List<double> second = [3,5,6,7,9,10];
List<double> output = [];

first.forEach((element) {
    if(!second.contains(element)){
    output.add(element);
}
});

//at this point, output list should have the answer
```

alternative answer:

```dart
List<double> first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
List<double> second = [3,5,6,7,9,10];
List<double> output = first.where((element) => !second.contains(element));
```

note that for both cases, you need to loop over the **larger list**.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any built in methods or libraries, or do I have to do it using a for each loop :(

Comment: I am not aware of a straight forward function, but I have added an alternative answer.

Comment: I had to add `.toList` at the end of the `output` to get it to work.

Comment: Your alternative answer rocks! I created a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/3b4d345e76d8c7dd3f0f571bdefcdfdb) to show the difference between diff'ing one list before the other.

Answer (score 30):

Since you will be looking for unique elements you could use the difference method of the Set class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set/difference.html) to do something like this:

```
List<int> first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
List<int> second = [3,5,6,7,9,10];
List<int> difference = first.toSet().difference(second.toSet()).toList();
print(difference.toString());
// prints [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: I like this answer but it want selected as correct. But it avoids the looping of the other

Answer (score 6):

Simple & Recommended Way to do this is

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2];
a.removeWhere((element) => b.contains(element));
print(a); //[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Note that this only finds elements in `a` that are not also in `b` which works for the particular example the OP gave. It is not the same as difference between two sets because it will not find the elements in `b` that are not in `a`. The React diffing algorithm used to update the current DOM tree or Git's diffing algorithm for text files needs to know what was removed, what was added and what was modified. The algorithm above would only give what was removed. That might be sufficient for your particular use case but not the general case.

Answer (score 4):

if you need single line , just do like this one

```dart
print([1,2,3,4,5,6,7].where((e) => ![3,5,6,7,9,10].contains(e)).toList());
```

result is

```dart
[1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```dart
void main() {
  final l1 = [1, 2, 3];
  final l2 = [3, 4, 5];
  print(listDiff(l1, l2)); // [1, 2, 4, 5]
}

List<T> listDiff<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) => (l1.toSet()..addAll(l2))
    .where((i) => !l1.contains(i) || !l2.contains(i))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!.contains` for nullable variable.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var b = [3,5,6,7,9,10];
a.removeWhere((element) => b!.contains(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
    var listA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    var listB = [3,5,6,7,9,10];
    listB.map((e)=>listA.remove(e)).toList();
    print(listA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `list.contains()` is an `O(n)` operation, other answers have terrible performance and don't consider duplicate elements in the lists.

[Myers diff algorithm](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/) can help if you want to diff two lists.

Here is the dart implementation by @knaeckeKami.

https://github.com/knaeckeKami/diffutil.dart

Answer (score 0):

Some people may be searching for the symmetric difference rather than strict difference provided in the standard library. Here is an extension to Set which adds a `symmetricDifference` function:

```dart
   extension on Set {
      /// Creates a set that is the _symmetric difference_ of this set and
      /// another set. That is the set of all elements that are in this
      /// set _or_ the other set, but not in _both_ sets.
      Set<E> symmetricDifference<E>(Set<E> other) =>
          difference(other).union(other.difference(this)) as Set<E>;
    }
    
    void main() {
      final Set l = {1, 2, 3};
      final Set r = {2, 3, 4};
      assert(l.difference(r) == {1});
      assert(r.difference(l) == {4});
      assert(l.symmetricDifference(r) == {1, 4});
    }
```