# How to get difference between two lists in dart?

Tags: list, dart

I am creating an app right now and I want to get the difference between two lists such:

```dart
List x = ['one' , 'two' , 'three' , 'four'];

List y = ['one' , 'two',];

------

Output: ['three' , 'four']
```

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633439/get-difference-of-lists-flutter-dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through one of the loop and then check if the item is present in the other list or not.

```dart
void main() {
  List x = ['one' , 'two' , 'three' , 'four'];
  List y = ['one' , 'two',];
  List output = [];

  for(final e in x){
    bool found = false;
    for(final f in y) {
      if(e == f) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found){
      output.add(e);
    }
  }
  print(output);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This might be easier if you can use [Set.difference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set/difference.html) instead.

If you're stuck with using lists this is a slightly shorter solution.

```
    var l = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var r = [3, 4];
    l.removeWhere((e) => r.contains(e));
    print(l);
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve a new list you can `newList = l.where((e) => !r.contains(e));`