# Comparing one list to another list and finding missing components using flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have two lists.

```
List animalsOne = ['Lion','Zebra','tiger','Chimpanzee','Rabbit'];
```

I also have a second list.

```
List animalsTwo = ['Lion', 'Girrafe', 'tiger', 'Dog', 'Chimpanzee','Rabbit'];
```

How do I compare the two to get an output showing the animals in List animalTwo that are missing in list animalsOne i.e. in this case Girrafe and Dog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get difference of lists flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633439/get-difference-of-lists-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Difference method of List. Try like below code.

```
List<String> animalsOne = ['Lion','Zebra','tiger','Chimpanzee','Rabitt'];
   List<String> animalsTwo = ['Lion', 'Girrafe', 'tiger', 'Dog', 'Chimpanzee', 'Rabbit'];

List<String> difference = animalsOne.toSet().difference(animalsTwo.toSet()).toList();
print(difference.toString());
```

Comment: That `difference` method belongs to `Set`, not `List`. As shown by the need to call `toSet()` on both of your lists.