# Comparing two lists and finding indices of changes Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

What is cleanest way to compare two list and find out different index, example:

```
list1 = ['M', 'A', 'N', 'H', 'T', 'U', 'A', 'N']
list2 = ['M', 'I', 'N', 'H', 'T', 'O', 'A', 'N']
```

How to get different index list `[1, 5]`

I was trying to loop each list, but it seem pretty awkward, is there any collection fuction to do this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633439/get-difference-of-lists-flutter-dart

Comment: I believe you meant to say `[1, 5]`, note the first index is 0

Comment: Oop sorry my mistake, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
final result = IterableZip([list1, list2])
    .mapIndexed((index, element) => element[0] != element[1] ? index : null)
    .whereNotNull()
    .toList();
```

This needs

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```